# In the Google App Engine Django Helper, is the app.yaml or the url.py file used to find the correct view?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm pretty new to this and while I'm pretty sure this is an easy question, I haven't been able to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, both.

http://markmail.org/message/4zhnpwylz6khhytb

Answer (score 2):

The `app.yaml` should point to the `main.py` that is included in the appengine helper. That way, you can create and use `urls.py` for your app.

Since you can point to any other view from `app.yaml`, it is possible you can use it directly without `urls.py`; but then it's not django anymore.